# Unity texture blurred despite everything being highres and uncompressed

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender

I have a model in Blender with perfectly highres textures. I export it as fbx, import it to Unity, import textures to unity at full res (and no mipmapping, point, no compression, etc) and still the texture looks extremely blurred. Any hints why that might be?

[Here's a comparison of the face in Blender vs Unity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xhNn.jpg)

[Here are the relevant, currently applied settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwojk.jpg). I've tried many, but imho those (extreme) settings should make 100% sure that the texture is on maximum quality.

EDIT: Interestingly, a close-up image reveals a seemingly high detail on the clothes below the face, yet not on the face itself. Maybe that's just my imagination. [Have a closer look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmrHp.jpg)

Thanks for some help!

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem, but you do have mipmapping enabled. Maybe post image of what does the imported texture actually look like (not in-game).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried disabling mipmapping already, the texture ingame looks exactly the same. Yet it also shouldn't have that impact anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to tell in the comparison shot you linked (as that itself is so low resolution), but the texture resolution looks the same. It doesn't look any more blurry in the Unity image.

To me it looks more like a shader + lighting issue. Are you using the Standard shader? Do you have additional maps that are not applied in the Unity material (like a normal map)?

Try lighting him with some point lights instead of just a hard directional light.

On a side note, 8192 is an absurdly high resolution for that guy. With how blurry the texture looks (in both Blender and Unity) you should be able to get the same detail with 512, at most 1024.

Comment: You were right to search somewhere else! In the end I replaced directional light with spotlight, put trilinear filtering, halved camera FOV  (for less distortion if e.g. the face is zoomed in), but by far largest impact: I put the same texture in the detail albedo x2 in its material! Now it looks even better than in Blender. Thanks a lot!